# How to make Ubuntu GNOME ignore VMware's vmnet8?

Tags: gnome, network-manager, vmware, ubuntu-gnome, vmware-workstation

I'm using **Ubuntu GNOME** 15.04 and **VMware Workstation** 12.0, which installs its virtual interface `vmnet8` for VMs' network connectivity through NAT. I'm using VMware on my laptop with ordinary `eth0` and `wlan0` interfaces. I don't have any other interfaces besides loopback.

Before VMware was installed, GNOME was displaying Wi-Fi interface in the top-right standard GNOME3 menu and also the Ethernet interface when the cable was plugged in. After VMware installation, it is now always displaying Ethernet interface as connected (probably due to detecting `vmnet8`), even though `eth0` is down. [A try at a visual explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmD79.png).

I have already added the following configuration lines into `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[main]
no-auto-default=*

[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:vmnet8
```

And I have also tried adding the `vmnet8` definition to `/etc/network/interfaces` (as NetworkManager should ignore interfaces defined there), but it did not help.

So my question is how to make NetworkManager/GNOME ignore `vmnet8` the way it's ignoring `lo` or Ethernet bridge interfaces (`virbr0` for example...)?

Answer (score 4):

I found a very simple solution for this problem.
Just type:

```
vmware-netcfg
```

in a terminal and remove the NAT and Host only Network interfaces, or any you want to get rid of.

Of course you can't use them from now on. You have to use the bridged connection.
For me this connection doesn't show up in the Gnome networkmanager.

Comment: That's the thing I wanted.. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't dealt with this personally but I did find a post that may help you.  [Helpful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321380/disable-network-manager-for-a-particular-interface)

Comment: Yes, it's probably the same thing. Although the difference is that VMware gets detected once and there is one menu entry too much, whereas the people commenting this bug report use VirtualBox and have many entries in the top-right menu. Thanks for the link!